# How do I draw polygon?( in C# WPF project)

Tags: c#, wpf, polygon, polyline

Click the points, I want to make from the polygon area on image.

```
myPolygon = new Polygon();
myPolygon.Stroke = Brushes.Black; 
myPolygon.Fill = Brushes.LightYellow; 
myPolygon.StrokeThickness = 2; 
myPolygon.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left; 
myPolygon.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center; 
myPolygon.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Polygon_MouseDown); 
myPolygon.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Polygon_MouseUp);     

private void Polygon_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
{     
    Point p = e.GetPosition(image); 
    myPolygon.Points = new PointCollection() { new Point(p.X,p.Y) };
    RootCanvas.Children.Add(myPolygon); 
} //MouseClick Event BUT, did not click behavior.. I want draw a line along the points.
```

How can I do...?

Comment: _Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results_

Comment: Use Blend, it have the tools...

Answer (score 12):

We can draw Polygon using WPF canvas which is a collection of children objects.

```
Polygon p = new Polygon();
p.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
p.Fill = Brushes.LightBlue;
p.StrokeThickness = 1;
p.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
p.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
p.Points = new PointCollection() { new Point(10, 10), new Point(100, 100), new Point(200, 200) };
freeCanvas.Children.Add(p);
```

For more information,. please refer the following urls

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128705/WPF-rounded-corners-polygon

http://classicalprogrammer.wikidot.com/draw-dynamic-polygons-in-wpf

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx

Comment: SRY I lost my source..
myPolygon = new Polygon();
            myPolygon.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            myPolygon.Fill = Brushes.LightYellow;
            myPolygon.StrokeThickness = 2;
            myPolygon.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            myPolygon.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
myPolygon.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Polygon_MouseDown);
            myPolygon.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Polygon_MouseUp);
//initialize

Comment: private void Polygon_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Point p = e.GetPosition(image);
            myPolygon.Points = new PointCollection() { new Point(p.X,p.Y)};
            RootCanvas.Children.Add(myPolygon);
        } //MouseClick Event

BUT, did not click behavior..
I want draw a line along the points.